# C# Read at a certain point of a line on text file

Tags: c#

Hi I need to read from a text file that is structured like this:

```
DataSource = WS****\SQLEXPRESS  
DataBase = *********  
UserName = sa  
PassWord = ****
```

Where stars are information about the database

However I want to only start reading from 1 space after the '=' where the information starts this is the code I have so

```
string fileLocation = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\SQLConfigSettings.txt";

if (!File.Exists(fileLocation))
{
    using (File.Create(fileLocation)) { }
}
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        fs.Seek(13, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        dataSource = sr.ReadLine();

        fs.Seek(11, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        dataBaseName = sr.ReadLine();
        MessageBox.Show(dataBaseName);

        fs.Seek(11, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        userName = sr.ReadLine();

        fs.Seek(11, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        passWord = sr.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

My thoughts were that this would seek the first line read, move down a line, seek again, read the line etc. The first line works, however the next lines just display the entirety of the lines.

Thanks!

Comment: `SeekOrigin.Begin` makes the file stream seek from the beginning of the file.  You may want to try `SeekOrigin.Current` instead.  Having said that, it would be better to just read the whole of each line, one by one, and parse each one from the `string`, rather than assuming that the file is in the correct format.

Comment: I got it sorted now thanks :) but current didn't seem to work for me either

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> lines = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.Default).ToList();

string dataSource = lines[0].Replace("DataSource = ", "");
string database = lines[1].Replace("DataBase = ", "");
string userName = lines[2].Replace("UserName = ", "");
string password = lines[3].Replace("PassWord = ", "");
```

Comment: This would produce the expected output, but it doesn't answer the question regarding why the seek to a specific location within the line of the file does not.